# Rendering docfx-built landing page from some html/javascript content

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, docfx

I have some .md files that are happily built into articles of a site generated by docfx.
The landing page of this site which at the moment is a index.md file is empty.
I have a separate static html page that its content is rendered by javascript containing some graph etc.
What I would like to do is to render this html content as the landing page of the docfx site.

How do I do that?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your use case, this worked for me:

Add **index.html** at root. This is your HTML landing page.

Reference **index.html** in the `resource` object in **docfx.json**:

```
"resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "articles/**/media/**",
          "index.html"
        ]
```

Reference **index.html** in **toc.yml** at root:

```
- name: Home
  homepage: index.html
```

Make sure you delete the previous site output directory (`_site` by default) before testing this new configuration.

I would expect there is a more sophisticated way but maybe this can get you started.